# What is the speed of laser pulse?

Tags: laser, speed

Consider 1064 nm wavelength pulsed fiber laser, that can generate up to one million pulses per second. Now I want to calculate the length of the pulse, and for this I require to know pulse's speed. Pulse duration is known. P.S.: I know, that the speed of light in vacuum is 3*10^8 m/s.

Answer (score 0):

Optical fiber typically has an index of refraction ($n$) of about 1.5. Therefore, the speed of your laser pulse is approximately $c_0/n = 2 \times 10^8$ m/s.